# How to make the git-status output show a few latest commit messages?

Tags: git

I just realized it could be pretty handy (gives you better "sense of context" for your commit when you do `git commit` for example) if `git-status` output a few latest commit messages instead of a mere `Your branch is ahead of ...` so that something like this

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   Gemfile.lock
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       models.html
#       script/rails_ssl
#       spec.txt
```

looks like this instead

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits:
# z1s4c8 Use Rack::SSL to force SSL, make cookies secure
# a5f7qw Fixed department filter
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   Gemfile.lock
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       models.html
#       script/rails_ssl
#       spec.txt
```

Short googling session didn't turn up anything great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do that in current git, based on an examination of `format_tracking_info` as of today (see [remote.c](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=remote.c;h=ca42a126ad04514f0ed8378768ebce98cfc5a659;hb=HEAD#l1589)).

Your best bet might be to send a feature request mail to git@vger.kernel.org.

Answer (score 2):

you can create an alias for log, such as:

```
git config --global alias.last 'log --oneline --decorate -n5'
```